# start selenium in Odoo with selenium driver

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I build a module on odoo and I use selenium to automate a task I create a function in python which allows to do it and when I execute it all works but when I integrate it into Odoo it does not work anymore when I click on the button to trigger the function no window opens I need help to operate selenium on Odoo

Comment: what window ? Browser window started by Selenium? Do you run it on server? if Selenium runs on server then it can display browser's window only on monitor connected directly to server - it can't display it remotly on other computer.

Comment: I work in localhost with an odoo server. how can i then properly execute selenium through odoo. My challenge is to automate the sending of whatsapp messages with Odoo I made the python code and they work perfectly with the selenium chrome driver and now I would like it to work on Odoo too

Comment: Ever managed to get this done? I'm trying to do something similar...